# May a UK academic employer ask the latest pay slip of my current Canadian job?

Tags: united-kingdom, employment, canada, academia, salary

As a postdoc in a Canadian institution, I have been offered a lecturer position in UK. In the offer email I have received, one clause reads as follows:

> Please could you provide evidence of your current salary by sending me
> your most recent pay slip.

Is it legally OK to ask this (particularly considering the fact that the job I have been offered is not in the same level of my current job)? Is there any law that supports my potential refusal to provide the desired pay slip?

Comment: Related: [Current salary disclosure in the UK](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/168725/124280)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They can ask, but there is nothing in law - that I can find - which obligates an answer. (There may be some exceptions that require a previous employer to [provide a reference](https://www.gov.uk/work-reference) which might include this detail, but that does not appear relevant here.)

As an aside, there is an ongoing *#EndSalaryHistory* campaign by the [Fawcett Society](https://www.fawcettsociety.org.uk/news/fawcett-society-calls-on-employers-to-stop-asking-salary-history) which is focused on equal pay and sexual equality in the workplace, and they are calling on employers to:

> stop asking salary history questions...

Comment: It originates from some schools of HR thought that will not employ a person for more than 10% of there previous salary. It is indeed a red flag.

Comment: I suppose what's really more important is whether the law provides any protection for someone who would prefer not provide the information. OP asks this, too, in the body of their question, though it probably should have been the title.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Do you possibly mean 110% of previous salary.  A mandatory 90% salary cut seems onerous...

Comment: @DJohnM as my highschool english teacher used to tell me. Your reading skills leave much to be desired. I mean exactly what I posted.